# Using a formula as a range

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a bit of an inventory tracking program in excel 2010 that we are using at my workplace.  It is used to track our chemical usage and packaged goods.

Currently it is a bit bulky, if we change a product from one tank to another, there is a bit of reprogramming that needs to be done every time.  I want a co-worker to be able to do all of this easily without knowledge of VBA.

There are different sized tanks that each have their own gauge chart that gets referenced by the program to determine volume removed or delivered etc.

So my question is...

Can I use a formula as a range?  I would then be able to just change a cell in the workbook so that the VBA programming would reference a different gauge chart.

P.S. - I have tried to find information on something like this but have turned up nil.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you post a small sample table of what you have and what you expect to happen? I kind of understand, but some (can be fake) data would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to find out about the function INDIRECT.

Comment: Or INDEX or whatever. The easiest way is to use a formula to get the particular value you want in its own section of the worksheet, and plot this range. The chart range doesn't move, but it changes as the formula updates.